# Responsive image overlay within another image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've successfully displayed an image over another image like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="image-with-overlay">
            <div class="shop-now-overlay">
                <img src="img/btn_shop_now.png">
            </div>
            <img src="img/left_image.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="image-with-overlay">
            <div class="shop-now-overlay">
                <img src="img/btn_shop_now.png">
            </div>
            <img src="img/right_image.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how my stylesheet looks like:

```
.image-with-overlay {
  position: relative;
}
.image-with-overlay .shop-now-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

But I want my page to be responsive and of course, everytime I resize my browser smaller and the images gets displayed on a single column (`col-sm-12`), the overlay button displays outside the image and takes the width of the page.
Any ideas on how I can restrict the image overlay to only wrap around the image even when the screen is smaller?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle and explain your problem through that??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `responsive.css` makes it static! Can you try with `!important`? I won't recommend this but checking doesn't hurt.

```css
.image-with-overlay {
    position: relative !important;

    .shop-now-overlay {
        position: absolute !important;
        z-index: 10;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `padding` element and try to handle the position with `left` and `right : 30px`

```
.shop-now-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;        
}
```